# How to match the elements of dictionaries for the given Python List of Dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries. I wanted to get the out put based on the start and close time. If two or more days are with same timings, they should be combined and displayed as shown in the output.

```
timings = [
    {'day': 'Monday', 'start': '8:00 am', 'close': '5:00 pm'},
    {'day': 'Tuesday', 'start': '7:00 am', 'close': '4:00 pm'},
    {'day': 'Wednesday', 'start': '7:00 am', 'close': '4:00 pm'},
    {'day': 'Thursday', 'start': '8:00 am', 'close': '5:00 pm'},
    {'day': 'Friday', 'start': '9:00 am', 'close': '4:00 pm'},
    {'day': 'Saturday', 'start': '9:00 am', 'close': '4:00 pm'},
    {'day': 'Sunday', 'start': '8:00 am', 'close': '5:00 pm'}
]
```

Output:

```
Monday            - 8:00 am - 5:00 pm

Tuesday-Wednesday - 7:00 am - 4:00 pm

Thursday          - 8:00 am - 5:00 pm

Friday-Saturday   - 9:00 am - 4:00 pm

Sunday            - 8:00 am - 5:00 pm
```

Comment: This is going to be annoyingly difficult using strings... probably a lot easier if you use datetime objects.

Comment: @AChampion yea, sure, but you still have with time as strings.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga not sure I see that as an issue, string comparison would be sufficient for this problem `'9:00am' == '9:00am' -> True`

Comment: @AChampion yeah, but `"9:00 am < 8:00 pm"` is `False` But actually, I just realized OP only wants *exact* overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution for this problem would be to use `itertools.groupby`, e.g.:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> for (start, close), days in it.groupby(timings, lambda t: (t['start'], t['close'])):
...   print('{:20} - {} - {}'.format('-'.join(d['day'] for d in days), start, close))
Monday               - 8:00 am - 5:00 pm
Tuesday-Wednesday    - 7:00 am - 4:00 pm
Thursday             - 8:00 am - 5:00 pm
Friday-Saturday      - 9:00 am - 4:00 pm
Sunday               - 8:00 am - 5:00 pm
```

Comment: Very nice! - Didn't realize that one could make use of the fact that the days are correctly ordered in `timings` and that `groupby` expects a list already sorted by the key. Maybe it would be helpful to add a (short) explanation of the latter fact?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried using string comparison and all. ended up with large code. @Jonathan Thanks for the explanation.